# Join two tables, Inserting values into second table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I tried searching here for a similar solution but didn't see one so I was wondering what is the best way to accomplish the following.
I have a table

```
Table1 t1
t1.c1 ..
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

values

and have another table like this

```
Table2 t2
t2.c1   t2.c2   t2.c3  ..
1         v1     v2
2         v3     v4
3         v5     v6
5         v7     v8  
7         v9     v10
```

I need to insert/update  table 2
where it has t2.c1 = 7 
so the result would look like this

```
t2.c1   t2.c2   t2.c3  ..
1         v1     v2
2         v3     v4
3         v5     v6
5         v7     v8  
1         v9     v10
2         v9     v10
3         v9     v10
4         v9     v10
5         v9     v10
6         v9     v10
```

I was trying to first see if there was in the column t2.c1 the value 7 .If existed them Insert the new rows . After the insert, delete the row with the value 7, but I really don´t know how to do so..
Can anyone give some ideias how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you need a cartesian product of tables `t2` and `t1` for all records where `t2.c1 = 7`, e.g.:

```
INSERT INTO Table2
SELECT t1.c1, t2.c2, t2.c3
FROM Table1 t1, Table2 t2
WHERE t2.c1 = 7
```

Followed by a deletion of those records with `t2.c1 = 7`, e.g.:

```
DELETE FROM Table2 t2 WHERE t2.c1 = 7
```

Answer (score 0):

First delete the c1=7 then populate it data from table1

```
DELETE FROM Table2
WHERE c1 = 7;

INSERT INTO Table2 (c1,c2,c3) 
SELECT t1.c1,t1.c2,t1.c3
FROM Table1 as t1;
```

[FIDDLE](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/e3UJVH3EayB4ywfdrHQcg3/0)